# HTML & JS Question: How to bring focus to an HTML input element if a a number, symbol or letter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, input, keyboard

**My question:**
How do I bring focus to an HTML `<input>` element if a number, letter or a special character on the keyboard is pressed (NOT ctrl, F1, F2...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add an event listener to the `document` element. This will trigger a function (preferably anonymous) that checks the key that was pressed and focuses on the `input` element when your desired key is pressed.
It will look like the following:

```
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
var pressedKey = event.key;
if(pressedKey === 'i') {
  input.focus();
 }
});
```

This will put focus on the `input` element with id `myInput` when the `i` key is pressed.

Check out the documentation on w3schools on [keyboardEvents key property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_key.asp) or [keyboardEvents](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp) in general for more information on this.